# Kendo grid every page has same data

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

In my kendo grid, I have it set to use paging, with a page size of 50. When the grid makes the Read request, I can see in the filters : Page 1, 50 rows , then the next page says Page 2, 50 rows, etc.

But every returning result has the same 50 rows ( from Page 1 ) .

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually in the controller / handler. In my GET Read request, I had the annotation for [FromBody] and it actually required using [FromQuery] . The [FromBody] tag is for POST requests only.

So even though the grid was sending the correct request, the handler was not receiving or relaying it to SQL correctly.

Changing the tag to [FromQuery] as shown below solved the problem.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetReadDataAsync([FromQuery][DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return new JsonResult(await db.table.ToListAsync().ToDataSourceResultAsync(request));
        }
```